# Android - Jelly Bean - YouTube play video only once

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I am using a WebView in order to play YouTube vidoes in my Android app.
It worked fine, but I seem to have a problem with Jelly Bean (and maybe later versions, I don't know yet).

The first time I play a video it works fine, but when I try to play it again  or even another video, **after closing the WebView and re-open it**, I see the video loading but then enters into pause mode (as can be seen in the image attched).

When closing the WebView I'm using this code, which I think is the cause of the problem:

```
Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView").getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null).invoke(webview, (Object[]) null);
```

Did someone encounter this problem?

Left image - the video is played normally.

Middle image - trying to load it again.

Right image - video is paused and never started.

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
private void loadUrl() 
{
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
            webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        } else {
            webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        }

        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wView, String url)
            {
                progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                webview.loadUrl(url);
                isLoading = true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, android.graphics.Bitmap favicon)
            {
                progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError (WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isLoading = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url)
            {
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isLoading = false;
            }
        });

        webview.loadUrl(url);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by clearing/destroying the webview:

```
         if (webview != null)
         {
             if (isLoading)
             { 
                    webview.stopLoading();
             }

             webview.clearCache(true);
             webview.clearView();
             webview.freeMemory();
             webview.destroy();  
         }
```