# html5 video tag video is playing only once

Tags: android, html, video, webview

I have a video which is playing only once in android webview,when i want to play it for the second time its not playing the video untill i repload the page

here the code:

```
area_div.innerHTML = '<video controls="controls" style="width:391px;height:289px" ><source src="cwvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>';
$("#contentAreaDiv").append(area_div);
```

Comment: There seems to be some issues with video in web views - it might be worth looking at: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63754 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584004/android-jelly-bean-youtube-play-video-only-once

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the `preload` to `metadata`. It will solve pausing and playback.

```
<video controls preload='metadata'></video>
```